# Not able to see typed text in input using react hooks and controlled components

Tags: reactjs, input, react-hooks, jsx, controlled-component

**//The value coming from the input that triggered the event is getting updated in the state but not displaying in the browser, I don't really understand what's happening, I have been using the same method to update the state in my other project**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
```

```
    const Register=()=>{

    const [user,setUser]=useState({
        name:"",
        email:"",
        password:"",
        reenterPassword:""
    });
    
    let changeHandler=(e)=>{
        const { name, value } = e.target
        setUser({
            ...user,
            [name]: value
        })
    
    }

    return(
        <div className="register">
            <h1>Register</h1>
            <input onChange={changeHandler}  name="Username" placeholder="Please Enter Your Name" type="text" defaultValue="" value={user.name}/>
            <input onChange={changeHandler} name="Email" placeholder="Enter your Email" type="email" value={user.email}/>
            <input onChange={changeHandler} name="Password" placeholder="Create Your Password" type="password" value={user.password}/>
            <input onChange={changeHandler} name="ReEnterPassword" placeholder="Re-Enter Your Password" type="password" value={user.reenterPassword}/>
            <div className="button">Register</div>
            <div>OR</div>
            <div className="button">Login</div>
        </div>
    )
}
export default Register;


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8beV.png
```

Comment: In addition to the answer that [stasdes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2091359/stasdes)  wrote, I must point out, that  your input names do not match with your `user` state object properties.

Comment: yeh that whats caused the trouble... but thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 1):

there is good answer here about it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58877875/2091359

you should not use useState like this, you can do useState for each input separately like this:

```js
  const [name, setName] = useState('')

  const handleChangeName = (e) => {
    setName(e.target.value);
  }

  return(
      <div className="register">
          <h1>Register</h1>
          <input onChange={handleChangeName} name="Username" placeholder="Please Enter Your Name" type="text" value={name}/>
          ...
```

or use useReduce

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
const Register=()=>{
const [user,setUser]=useState({
        Username:"",
        Email:"",
        Password:"",
        ReEnterPassword:""
    });
    
    let changeHandler=(e)=>{
        const { name, value } = e.target
        setUser({
            ...user,
            [name]: value
        })
    }
    return (
          <div className="register">
            <h1>Register</h1>
            <input onChange={(e)=>changeHandler(e)}  name="Username" placeholder="Please Enter Your Name" type="text" defaultValue="" value={user.name}/>
            <input onChange={(e)=>changeHandler(e)} name="Email" placeholder="Enter your Email" type="email" value={user.email}/>
            <input onChange={(e)=>changeHandler(e)} name="Password" placeholder="Create Your Password" type="password" value={user.password}/>
            <input onChange={(e)=>changeHandler(e)} name="ReEnterPassword" placeholder="Re-Enter Your Password" type="password" value={user.reenterPassword}/>
            <div className="button">Register</div>
            <div>OR</div>
            <div className="button">Login</div>
        </div>
      );
}
export default Register;
```

You need to use the same name for the html input attribute too, and try to use callback in the onChange event.